# cucumber-js in NX workspace and typescript, can not find module (shared library)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, cucumberjs, nx-workspace

I have a NX workspace with Angular and NestJS in it. I also have some shared libraries. I want to test an NestJS API project which uses one of the shared libraries generated with

```
nx g @nrwl/nest:lib shared/backend
```

I simply use it then in my NestJS project like a normal import over the name assigned by NX. Works good when I run the project itself in development mode, but when I run the application with the @nestjs/testing module, it fails.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@proj/shared/backend'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api\src\app\proj\proj.controller.ts
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api\src\app\proj\proj.module.ts
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api\src\app\app.module.ts
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api-e2e\step-definitions\step-definition.base.ts
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\lib\cli\run.js
- C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\@cucumber\cucumber\bin\cucumber-js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api\src\app\proj\proj.controller.ts:22:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1310:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1313:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api\src\app\proj\proj.module.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1310:23)
codepath: C:\Users\ebaamic\Projects\proj\apps\proj-api-e2e\step-definitions\step-definition.base.ts
```

When removing the library reference from my API code, my tests are running well, so its really only in the cucumber test. Here is how I create the testing module:

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [AppModule],
}).compile();
this.context.app = moduleFixture
  .createNestApplication()
  .useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
await this.context.app.init();
```

To start the e2e tests, I call the following command:

```
cucumber-js -p proj-api
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@proj/shared/backend": [
                "libs/shared/backend/src/index.ts"
            ],
            "@proj/shared/client": [
                "libs/shared/client/src/index.ts"
            ],
            "@proj/shared/common": [
                "libs/shared/common/src/index.ts"
            ],
            "@proj/shared/eds": [
                "libs/shared/eds/src/index.ts"
            ],
            "@proj/shared/feature": [
                "libs/shared/feature/src/index.ts"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

My cucumber.js in root

```
module.exports = {
  'proj-api': [
    'apps/proj-api-e2e/features/**/*.feature', // Specify our feature files
    '--require-module ts-node/register', // Load TypeScript module
    '--require apps/proj-api-e2e/step-definitions/**/*.ts', // Load step definitions
    '--format progress-bar', // Load custom formatter
    '--publish-quiet',
    '--parallel 0',
    '--exit',
  ].join(' '),
};
```

And here are my dependencies in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.0",
    "@nestjs/axios": "0.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.0.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.0",
    "cache-manager": "^3.4.4",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.1",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.0",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.3.1",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.11",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.8",
    "@nrwl/angular": "^12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/jest": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/linter": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/nest": "^12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/node": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.9.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.9.0",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.28.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^6.0.0",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^4.0.0-preview.7",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0",
    "cypress-fail-on-console-error": "^2.1.2",
    "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "27.0.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "9.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "testcafe": "^1.16.0",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.37",
    "typeorm-extension": "^0.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
},
```

It looks like cucumber-js does not use the tsconfig where the libraries are defined, because when I run the code normal it works, and when I remove the lib import my test works also.

Has someone any idea?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Somehow or better not :) I moved away from cucumber-js and implemented cypress-cucumber-preprocessor which was not the easiest task because this one needs a setting in package.json to work, for every app it needs to get adjusted. So I have added a script which adjusts the package.json before the test run. But that works finally.

Comment: @MichaelBaarz do you mind posting more details/code. I've run into a similar issue and can't get past this. It seems the only work around is to import using the relative path which is super ugly and prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Install tsconfig-paths

> npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths

Register the module in cucumber.js (root)

```
./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js ... \
   --require-module ts-node/register \
   --require-module tsconfig-paths/register \
   ...
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).